# What is the most efficient way to send data to a server from mobile js/html5 and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, html, entity-framework, sencha-touch

I am developing a mobile app, and want to use the least amount of resources sending data to an entity framework server. The app is being developed in Sencha Touch 2.0, using the Extjs 4 framework. My question is how do I send data in the most efficient way possible?

Some of the datatypes are,
login credentials,
zip'd audio files,
credit card data,
and settings.

Answer (score 0):

As you are sending sensible data, you might want to encrypt the data before sending them. Then as a second step you might want to work with rest calls and use an SSL connection.

You can try to pin the SSL Seerver and work with OAUTH2.